# Composer Issues when trying to install a package globally

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I uploaded a package to packagist, and ran this command to require it globally:

```
composer global require emmajiugo/flutterwave-cli
```

This failed with the following output:

```
Changed current directory to /Users/emmanuelezejiugo/.composer
Using version ^1.3 for emmajiugo/flutterwave-cli
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for emmajiugo/flutterwave-cli ^1.3 -> satisfiable by emmajiugo/flutterwave-cli[v1.3].
    - Conclusion: remove illuminate/container v5.8.28
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/container v5.8.28
    - emmajiugo/flutterwave-cli v1.3 requires laravel-zero/framework ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel-zero/framework[v7.0.0, v7.1.0, v7.2.0, v7.2.1].
    - laravel-zero/framework v7.0.0 requires illuminate/container ^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.15.0, v7.16.0, v7.16.1, v7.17.0, v7.17.1, v7.17.2, v7.18.0, v7.19.0, v7.19.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.20.0, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
    - laravel-zero/framework v7.1.0 requires illuminate/container ^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.15.0, v7.16.0, v7.16.1, v7.17.0, v7.17.1, v7.17.2, v7.18.0, v7.19.0, v7.19.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.20.0, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
    - laravel-zero/framework v7.2.0 requires illuminate/container ^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.15.0, v7.16.0, v7.16.1, v7.17.0, v7.17.1, v7.17.2, v7.18.0, v7.19.0, v7.19.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.20.0, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
    - laravel-zero/framework v7.2.1 requires illuminate/container ^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.15.0, v7.16.0, v7.16.1, v7.17.0, v7.17.1, v7.17.2, v7.18.0, v7.19.0, v7.19.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.20.0, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.0.0, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.0.1, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.0.2, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.0.3, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.0.4, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.0.5, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.0.6, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.0.7, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.0.8, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.1.0, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.1.1, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.1.2, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.1.3, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.10.0, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.10.1, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.10.2, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.10.3, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.11.0, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.12.0, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.13.0, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.14.0, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.14.1, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.15.0, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.16.0, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.16.1, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.17.0, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.17.1, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.17.2, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.18.0, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.19.0, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.19.1, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.2.0, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.2.1, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.2.2, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.20.0, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.3.0, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.4.0, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.5.0, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.5.1, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.5.2, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.6.0, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.6.1, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.6.2, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.7.0, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.7.1, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.8.0, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.8.1, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.9.0, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.9.1, v5.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.9.2, v5.8.28].
    - Installation request for illuminate/container (locked at v5.8.28) -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.8.28].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I have tried changing a few things on my `composer.json` file and still getting the issue. Below is my `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "emmajiugo/flutterwave-cli",
    "description": "A CLI app that helps you test Flutterwave payment on the go and also generate sample apps.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "flutterwave", "rave", "rave cli", "flutterwave cli", "rave console", "flutterwave console", "cli"],
    "homepage": "https://flutterwave.com",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/emmajiugo/flutterwave-cli/issues",
        "source": "https://github.com/emmajiugo/flutterwave-cli"
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Chigbo Ezejiugo",
            "email": "emmajiugo@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "laminas/laminas-text": "^2.7",
        "laravel-zero/framework": "^5.8",
        "padraic/phar-updater": "^1.0.6",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^4.0",
        "yuloh/open": "^0.1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php application app:rename"
        ]
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "bin": ["flutterwave"]
}
```

Comment: What composer command did you run on the command-line to get that output? Are you working with globally installed packages? It looks like the relevant `composer.json` is the one in `/Users/emmanuelezejiugo/.composer`, can you show us that?

Comment: I ran this command to require it globally `composer global require emmajiugo/flutterwave-cli` @IMSoP

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to read the error message? One line tells you the problem:

> emmajiugo/flutterwave-cli v1.3 requires laravel-zero/framework ^7.0

On the other hand, your `composer.json` requires `"laravel-zero/framework": "^5.8"` - these two requirements obviously do not work together. You should either require a lower version of Laravel in your library, or require a later version of Laravel in your application

Comment: initially, it was `"laravel-zero/framework": "^7.0"`...but I am still having the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Composer's "global install" functionality works by setting up a Composer project in a particular directory and managing it in the normal way. As [the manual states](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global):

> The global command allows you to run other commands like install, remove, require or update as if you were running them from the COMPOSER_HOME directory.
>
> This is merely a helper to manage a project stored in a central location that can hold CLI tools or Composer plugins that you want to have available everywhere.

This is key to understanding the output you saw, which begins:

> Changed current directory to /Users/emmanuelezejiugo/.composer

Everything after this happens *as though you'd run a normal composer command in that directory*.

The first part of the conflict is fairly straight-forward:

- emmajiugo/flutterwave-cli v1.3 requires laravel-zero/framework ^7.0
- laravel-zero/framework v7.x requires illuminate/container ^7.0

The reason that's causing a conflict shows up right at the end of the message:

- Installation request for illuminate/container (locked at v5.8.28)

This is referring to you having "locked" that package to a particular version in the `composer.json` *for the project where you're currently installing packages*. In other words, you're trying to add two requirements for that project that contradict each other.

As we've established above, that project is *not* your new library, it is the project composer has created in `/Users/emmanuelezejiugo/.composer`. So the configuration you need to change is in `/Users/emmanuelezejiugo/.composer/composer.json`.

The simplest solution is probably *not to install the library in that folder*. As noted above, the `composer global` command isn't actually doing anything other than changing directory for you; most of the time, you're better off creating a directory for each project or tool and requiring its dependencies there, even if you only need a local copy to run some commands.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.

I ran `composer global update` and it updated all the required packages.
Then did `composer global require repo-name/repo-package-name` and it worked fine.